# Error Code: 1241. Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Tags: mysql, errors

this is a program to compare three numbers to find greatest

```
INSERT INTO compare(a,b,c)
values(43,56,2);

SELECT a,b,c,
IF (a>b AND a>c,'a is greatest',
       (SELECT a,b,c,
       IF (b>c,'b is greatest','c is greatest')
       )
   )
AS  greatest           
FROM compare;
```

And the error:
Error Code: 1241. Operand should contain 1 column(s)
Please tell why is the error and how to improve.thanking everybody for their help.

Comment: Is there a minimum value for a, b, c? (ex. 0)

Comment: What should happen if two of the columns are equal?  Eg, (1,2,2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason to select a second time after your first if statement. Just make the 2nd test for b being greater than c in the ELSE of the first if statement.

```
SELECT a,b,c,
 IF (a>b AND a>c,'a is greatest',IF (b>c,'b is greatest','c is greatest'))
 AS  greatest           
 FROM test
```

Comment: Minor nitpick: if the columns are nullable, then for `(a,b,c,) = (2,1,null)`, your expression (and McNets's, in the other answer) will show `'c is greatest'` ;)

Answer (score 1):

Using CASE:

Note I've used COALESCE(column,  to avoid NULL values for a, b or c. But I don't know which is the minimum allowed value.

```
SELECT a, b, c,
       CASE WHEN (a > b OR b IS NULL) AND (a > c OR C IS NULL) THEN 'a is greatest'
            WHEN (b > C OR c IS NULL) THEN 'b is greatest
            ELSE 'c is greatest'
       END AS  greatest           
FROM compare;
```

Comment: Instead of `COALESCE()` and a fixed constant `<min_value>` which has to be different for different types, I'd use something like this, when we want to ignore nulls: `CASE WHEN (a>b OR b IS NULL) AND (a>c OR c IS NULL) THEN a WHEN b>c OR c IS NULL THEN b ELSE c END`